# eshell - completion-at-point sometimes add an extra space after selecting

Tags: eshell

for example, in eshell, I have

```
cd ~/Download/some$
```

where $ is where the cursor is. If I type Tab to invoke completion-at-point, after selecting the completion candidate, it would add one white space to it, so it becomes

```
cd ~/Download/somefolder/ $
```

while I would expect

```
cd ~/Download/somefolder/$
```

so I o continue to change directory.

This strange behavior only happens to some folders, and I can't find a pattern so far.

Comment: What is <kbd>tab</kbd> boud to? Use <kbd>C-h tab</kbd> to tell. On mine It is `eshell-pcomplete`.  You may want to use EDebug to step through the execution to see what's happening on the specific folder.  You may want to provide more detail about your setup and the actual instances of the problem.

Comment: Tab is bound to completion-at-point. i think it's by default as i didn't have any config for eshell. i will try EDebug.